# Trying to stretch a background downwards, but a white space remains

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image, stretch

I am busy placing my HTML site into a wordpress template. It is working out so far but i'm stuck at the background. At large pages the background stops and shows a big white space.

The background consists stripes, but also has a gradient fade from dark (up) to light (down).

I am trying to stretch the background down to the bottom of the screen. That works with pages
 smaller than my screen, but larger pages where I need to scroll down, the background stops and shows a big white space.

I am in need of some help here - I've tried a lot of solutions where some solved my problems with the large pages, but then the problem exists at the smaller pages. I hope there is a solution to stretch this background all the way down, on every page.

Current code (works on small pages, but problems on large pages)

```
html
{
    background: url(images/lines-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

But when I add this to the html css, the problem occurs then at the small pages..

```
    background-size: auto 100%;
```

I also want the background to be scrollable, not fixed.

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve this problem, I moved the css code from html to body and added some extra things to make sure:

```
html
{
    min-height:100%;    
}

body
{
    min-height:100%;
    background: url(images/lines-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 things you can try if you don't have to support super old browsers:

you can use the `background-attachment: fixed;` property that fixes the initial way the background is loaded to the page even when scrolling.

Or you can use `background-size:cover;` property which stretches the background to cover the size of the content area dynamically.  THis isn't always the best solution though as image quality can become an issue and inconsistent background arise from different page lengths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Background-size seems to blur the entire image over the screen [link](http://puu.sh/3Ic8n.png). I will keep the background-attachment solution in my mind, but I also want the background to be scrollable (if possible, ofcourse).

Comment: @MarnixBent  Yeah, background-size:cover; stretches the image to fit the contents.  Its rendering blurry because you have a really skinny really tall image and its stretching it equally height wise as it is to stretch it width wise to fit the screen.  You can reduce the height of your background image to fix this but there will still likely be some variation.  You coud try to see how it looks if you make your background-image screen width instead of 2px for starters.    Another approach is to have the vertical gradient fade into a solid color you set as your background-color underneath.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the background? When you say `background-size: auto 100%` it is setting the background image to be 100% of the size it is. Ex: if a image was 100px and you said `background-size: auto 100%` it would tell the image to be 100px and if you did `background-size: auto 50%` it would tell the image to be 50px. I believe that is your problem.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought 100% was meant 100% of the height of html. The background image is 2x1400px. But still, pages larger than 1400px in height are causing white spaces.

Comment: What I would recommend is using jquery to get the height of the window and then set the background image height in pixels. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HbrDf/

Comment: I would love to implement that js but I don't know how. I currently have this in my header:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('body').css('background-height' , $(window).height());
                });
            });
        </script>
`

Comment: Put <script> $( document ).ready(function() { $('body').css('background-height' , $(window).height()); }); }); </script> in your the body of your html.